# Make an array that is made with "eval" global

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 functions. In the first function I declare an array, with a name of an answer from the user, I do that with `eval`.

```js
function whengetanswerfrominput()
{
    var answer = document.getElementById("input").value;
    eval("var " + answer + " = ['bla','bla'];");
}
function whenclickotherbutton()
{
    var answer = document.getElementById("input").value;
    eval(answer + ".push('bla');");
}
```

But then I get an error that says that the second `eval` in `whenclickotherbutton()` is not defined.
How can I declare the array so that he knows it, in the second function.

```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined.
```

Comment: If you need to use eval, you are coding things wrong 99% of the time

Comment: typo error : `var  xxx = [bla,bla]` is invalid and must be `var  xxx = ['bla','bla']` with quotes around your strings, if not your array was not defined

Comment: Define an object `var questions = {};` Add to it `question[answer] = ['blah', 'blah'];` and push to it
`question[answer].push('blah');`

Comment: and also your element `answer` is out of your desired scope

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Please click the check mark on any of the answers below to mark this question as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `eval` at all.

```
function whengetanswerfrominput()
{
    var answer = document.getElementById("input").value;
    window[answer] = ["foo", "bar"];
}

function whenclickotherbutton()
{
    var answer = document.getElementById("input").value;    
    window[answer].push("baz");
}
```

Altough you should really consider to refrain from polluting the global scope this way, unless it's absolutely necessray (which in most cases it isn't)

Comment: better to use an object and not window.... no need to pullute the global namespace.

Comment: @epascarello That's why I wrote the comment below the code ...

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this `ReferenceError` is because you are defining the variable inside the scope of first function (`whengetanswerfrominput`). You cannot access this inside the second function because you initialized it in the first function.

You have to initialize the variable **outside** the second function to access it.

```js
var answer = document.getElementById("input").value;
eval("var " + answer + " = ['bla','bla'];");

function whenclickotherbutton()
{
    var answer = document.getElementById("input").value;
    eval(answer + ".push('bla');");
}
```

Comment: Where's the closure? You're not returning anything from that function.

Comment: @Andy my bad, forgot you need to return something in a closure.

Comment: @Andy also, does it really need to return something from the function? He never intended to return something in the first place.

Comment: No. But closures are very specific in their function which is why I pointed it out.